# Scala syntax question in Rocket-chip config.scala

Tags: scala, chisel, rocket-chip

I just learned about the scalar to study rocket chips.
I see some strange codes in the [Config.scala](https://gitlab.larc-nthu.net/jtxiao/FaultInjectionPlatform/-/blob/47332ea23cfac532aabc7171373885d6a49949c0/src/riscv-mini/lib/src/main/scala/config/Config.scala) of Rocket-chip

```scala
abstract class Field[T] private (val default: Option[T])
{
   def this() // 1st-this
              = this(None) // 2nd-this
   def this(default: T) // 3rd-this
              = this(Some(default)) // 4th-this
}
```

The above code has 4 of **this**. I think **2nd/4th-this** are identical.
But I'm not sure **2nd/4th-this** are represent **Field** class self-type or not.
If they are self-type, **1st/3rd-this** are to be what??
I'm frustrated since I can't tell the definition of the above four **this**.
Could you explain this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are called **auxiliary constructors** (see https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/book/domain-modeling-tools.html#classes).

The "main constructor" is the one defined by the class declaration:

```scala
class Field[T] private (val default: Option[T])
```

With this you can create instances of `Field` only by passing a `Option[T]`. Like `Field(None)` or `Field(Some(...))`.

---

Then, you have 2 additional auxiliary constructors. They are defined as regular methods but they need to be called `this`.

The following adds a constructor that accepts no parameter so that you can create instances with `Field()` and it will be the same as `Field(None)`. The 2nd `this` refers to the main constructor.

```scala
def this() = this(None)
```

Same principle for the other auxiliary constructors which allows to call `Field(x)` instead of `Field(Some(x))`.

---

Note that you could achieve the same with `apply` methods in a companion object.

Comment: Thank you for the easy explanation and link!

Comment: @astrohan By the way, a hint about the UI: if you found an answer useful, there is also the possibility to _upvote_ (additionally to _accept_-ing the answer)